# How to restrict copying content from a text item of Oracle Forms 10g?

Tags: forms, developer-tools

I need your help on the below

My requirements, need to restrict the Copy text from a Database item. It is one of text item, need to force keying the text and should not allow user to copy text from this item from any method either Ctrl+V, context menu.

We can do this by setting concealed property but text will appear *, it is not password field.

I tried copy_region, and CHR commands but no luck. It can be done through java but better by forms.

Could you help me to achieve this?

Thanks Maran

Tried Copy_region, chr function to stop this but not working for me.

Comment: Its Oracle Forms developer 10g

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For my requirements, needed to stop user from copy content in a text item. It is Oracle Forms screen.